# python convert ls -l style date

Tags: python

I have some output which is like ls -l, i.e.

```
drwxr-x---.   2 root   root     4.0K Nov 10  2014 sudoers.d
----------.   1 root   root     1.1K Nov 18 15:12 shadow-
-rw-r--r--.   1 root   root     1.7K Jan 13 21:18 motd
drwxr-xr-x.   2 root   root     4.0K Feb 13 15:29 snmp
```

What's the best way to convert the date/time into some usable format (YYMMDD, epoch, etc.) for sorting, using python ?

I can't change the output I'm given unfortunately, so have to work with it.

I'm sure this has been solved before, but I can't seem to find the solution. As you can see the format is:

```
%b %d %H:%M
```

unless it's older than 6 months ago, in which case

```
%b %d %Y
```

I haven't tried solving this in code yet, as I'm really hoping there's some utility function I've missed somewhere, given it's a somewhat common format.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include what you have tried. Does it work?

Comment: don't understand what you want to do ..

Comment: @YogendraSharma as stated, I want to get the string date format into a usable format for sorting, ideally by some simple function like strptime.

Answer (score 4):

1. For each line, grab all text between the fourth and seventh group of spaces, so that you have an array of strings like: `"Nov 10  2014" "Nov 18 15:12"` etc.  You can capture this text with a regex.
2. Next, test whether each element of the array contains a `:`.  That will tell you whether to use `"%b %d %H:%M"` or `"%b %d %Y"`
3. Use `datetime.strptime` with the conditional date format described above.

Comment: Thanks, yes those were the lines I was thinking along if I have to code it - was hoping for some existing function (yes I'm lazy!)

Comment: Of course I'm also going to have to worry about adding a year if in the previous 6 months (either current or previous, if I'm in first 6 months of year).

Answer (score 1):

use glob and os.path.getmtime will solve this for you

```
import os
import glob
# get the current working dir
path = os.getcwd()
files = glob.glob('%s/*' % path)
for file in files:
    #gets the modified time in epochs
    mtime = os.path.getmtime(file)
    print file, mtime
```

Comment: This solution assumes that the OP has access to the OS that produced the output, which is not quite what he asked, and seems like an unwarranted assumption because he states "I can't change the output I'm given unfortunately, so have to work with it."   Otherwise, I agree that this is the ideal approach.